# How do I add an email link in my app that works even if the user has uninstalled Mail.app?

Tags: ios, email, ios10, uninstallation, mailto

I want to provide an email link in my app for users to send feedback. I can use a mailto link, but if the user has uninstalled Mail.app (the inbuilt mail app), iOS puts up a dialog saying that it has been uninstalled, and telling the user how to restore it.

I don't want this to happen. Instead, I want to use another email app if it exists, like Gmail or Inbox. And if there are multiple third-party email apps, the user should get a choice, rather than the app picking one randomly.

How do I do that?

Ideally in a way that works with all apps, rather than hardcoding specific apps to check for, like:

```
if Inbox is installed {
  open Inbox
} else if Gmail is installed {
  open Gmail
} else if Outlook is installed {
  open Outlook
}
```

... which obviously doesn't work if the user uses an app other than these three.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add query scheme for gmail and outlook.
And then you will need to check whether your app can open it or not. 
If your app can then go ahead otherwise check for other in elseif condition.

like this..

```
NSString *gmailmURL = @"googlegmail://";
NSString *outllokURL = @"outlook://";

if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:gmailURL]])
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:gmailmURL]];
else if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] 
   canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:outlookURL]])
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:outllokURL]];
```

You can add more info in gmail by appending url like this

```
googlegmail://co?subject=Example&body=ExampleBody
```

There must be something like this for outlook also...